# Unable to ping IPv6 from docker container

Tags: docker, ping, ipv6

I am using `rancher desktop` to run a docker container (OS - Oracle Linux 7) locally. `ifconfig` output of my docker container:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2310  bytes 331965 (324.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2302  bytes 427593 (417.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When I use `ping6` or `ping -6` commands e.g. `ping6 ipv6.google.com`, I get the error:

> ping: ipv6.google.com: Name or service not known

What am I missing?

**EDIT :**  I already tried [Docker ping ipv6 endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906686/docker-ping-ipv6-endpoint) . Actually , there was no existing /etc/docker/daemon.json in my container / MAC. So I tried by creating and adding content as explained in the post on both my local machine (MAC) as well as inside container. But it did not work for me.

Comment: Did you [enable ipv6 in docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/)?

Comment: @ZacAnger I already tried this. Actually , there was no existing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in my container. But I tried by creating and adding content as explained in the post. But it did not work for me.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I already tried this. Actually , there was no existing `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in my container. But I tried by creating and adding content as explained in the post. But it did not work for me.

Comment: @tryingToLearn that configuration must be set in the host, not the container

Comment: @ti7 thanks , I set the config on my host , restarted the machine (not just docker service) , but still I get the same error.